# how to upload users to my OSQA site

Tags: python, django, upload, osqa

I want to upload some existing users from another site to my current OSQA site. I have an Excel file with the users I want to upload, their usernames and their emails.

I've found this http://meta.osqa.net/questions/10600/how-do-i-bulk-upload-users-and-questionsanswers-data-into-osqa and this http:// meta.osqa.net/questions/4080/how-can-i-import-data-from-another-question-and-answer-script

But both do not work for me.

I use Python and Django, like OSQA.

Comment: Why are they dont work? Could you provide ANY details?

Comment: When I try to execute on of the scripts to add users, an error with the database occurs:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/osqa/apps/osqa/forum_modules/mysqlfulltext/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/osqa/apps/osqa/../osqa/forum_modules/mysqlfulltext/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb`

If my site is running properly is because it already has mysqldb, so I do not understand why it is saying that.

Comment: Are you executing the script from virtualenv? If so, try to "import MySQLdb" from python shell and let me know what does it says.

Comment: Not really. I have installed OSQA with the Bitnami Mac Installer (my dev stack). I have already tried to do sth like pip install MySQLdb and all of those tips, and it always occurs the following error:
`(...)
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
(...)
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!
I have managed to solve both problems:

MySQL does not find mysql-config: the path was not correct. The correct one, after re-installed mysql: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql-config

psycopg2-extensions not found : re-install psycopg2 with homebrew and it worked!